# Prove that if $a^p - 1$ is prime, then $a = 2$ or $p = 1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am having difficulties with how to do this proof:
Let $a$ and $p$ be natural numbers. Prove that if $a^p-1$ is prime, then $a=2$ or $p=1$.

Comment: Hint: $a-1$ will divide $a^p-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a^p-1= (a-1)(a^{p-1}+\ldots + a^1 + 1)$ is a factorization. If the number is prime then $a-1$ is prime or $a-1=1$, i.e. $a=2$. If $a-1$ is prime, $a^{p-1}+\ldots + 1=1$ which means $p-1=0$, so $p=1$ is the other option since the number of summands is exactly $p$ in the second factor and they are all positive numbers.